# Try catch and print to screen

Tags: php, try-catch

I'm trying to build a quiz

This is a sample of a try catch that I am using.   The main thing I am trying to create is an online quiz and when the "submit" button is clicked I want the results to print to the screen.

The try catch works but it is pointless right now because it does not require user interaction.  The results are hard coded.

This is an example of my my html and try catch that I have so far.

My question is how to I get that to occur?

```
                <p>Which Basketball team is known as the Hoosiers

                    <select>
                        <option value="">--Select--</option>
                        <option value="IU">IU</option>
                        <option value="Kentucky">Kentucky</option>
                        <option value="Ohio State">Ohio State</option>
                        <option value="Connecticut">Conneticut</option>
                    </select> 

                </p>
                </br>
                 <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
                </form>

                                 <?php
        $quiz = 'IU';

        try { 

        //The answer is correct

        if ($quiz == 'IU') {
            echo 'Well Done!!!.';
                }else{
                    throw new Exception ('Not even close.');
        }

        //That is incorrect

                }catch (exception $wrg) {
            echo 'Error: ' .$wrg->getMessage();

        }

        ?>
```

Comment: Try catch is for catching (and dealing with in some way) PHP programmatic errors, not for simple user input. You're much better off just using the if/else...

Comment: @BenGriffiths: Exceptions are **not** for handling errors

Comment: The purpose of a try catch block is to catch program data errors, not to use as an if else or switch statement. That is a really bad habit you should break now.

Comment: Why to make it so complicated? Simple conditions can make it work.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I would have to seriously disagree with you.  Try catch statements are for catching unexpected results giving you a chance to gracefully break out.  (IE error handling).  I have never once seen anyone try to use it in this way, the poster should be using a switch statement or an if else statement.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Try catch is designed to attempt to run code and then catch any errors that may arise when attempting... Even the PHP docs use that type of scenario for it's examples.

Comment: @BenGriffiths: (a) Errors and exceptions are distinct. Read _any_ good book on programming. (b) The PHP docs are notoriously horrendous. (c) "its"

Comment: @thenetimp: Exceptions, as their name suggests, are for handling exceptional circumstances or conditions. **Not** errors.

Comment: From wiki: Exception - An action that is not part of ordinary operations or standards. So whether you want to argue about whether something's an error or an exception - it doesn't matter. Try/Catch is designed to catch a "problem with the code" that wasn't expected. The use of it as it's displayed in this question is wrong. By the way, calling me on that tiny grammar error, really? This isn't the place for being petty. I'm sure someone with 50k in rep should know that.

Comment: Thanks @BenGriffiths I was just going to post that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question you're asking is how do you read in the results from the quiz. You can do this through the global $_POST variable, you will need to name your select though like so `<select name="answer">` and then you can access it through $_POST['answer'] to get the selection value. Then you can compare it, you should not be using a throw exception with a try-catch block here, it's not really designed for using it for program logic. Instead you should just try a simple if else in this case e.g.

```
if(array_key_exists('answer', $_POST){
    if ($_POST['answer'] == 'IU') {
        echo 'Well Done!!!.';
    } else {
        echo 'Not even close.';
    }
}
```